# php Error message not browsed inside an include() function

Tags: php, error-handling, php-include

I have a problem when testing my php code file. Despite having error handling in test mode (I mean, 8191 E_ALL), the errors of the code that is added within an included file are not browsed, and the execution of the script is stopped. If the included file is large, I spend many time until I find the error, what can I do to display the error even if it is inside an included file?

Example:file code.php

```
echo '<p>beginning of the script</p>';
include_once('code2.php'); 
echo '<p>end of the script</p>';
```

The file code2.php has a parse error:

```
echo 'hello'
```

The script is stopped before browsing "end of the script", but no error messages are browsed.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This code does not execute bcoz php thinks `code2.php` is a variable, to fix that surround it with single quotes `'code2.php'` .

In order to see errors messages make sure you have `<?php` not just `<?` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Hi progSri, this was just an example, for sure the string 'code2.php' was between codes, otherwise as you said it wouldn't run, I just edited the question.

Comment: Hi progSri, it doesn't work to me, the parse error is not browsed, despite having error_reporting to ALL, what could be wrong?

Comment: @Gerard  did you have `<?php`  .
is it possible to post the code?

Comment: Hi progrSri, the code is the one I posted to you, can you see the parse error browsed when you run the file code.php?